# Sorting number values stored as a BigDecimal type with Spring Data MongoDB in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sorting, bigdecimal, spring-data-mongodb

I'm studying Spring Data MongoDB with a tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/data/2/).
In this tutorial, the type of cost is BigDecimal as following and it is stored as a "string" in MongoDB.
So, when I tried to get a sort result with an ascending sort by the cost field, I got a wrong result.

I found that using the BigDecimal class is the best way for calculations. 
But, if I save numbers as a BigDecimal type with Spring Data MongoDB in MongoDB, 
it will be saved as a string type
and I will get a wrong sort result like this tutorial.

What can I do to get a right sort result in terms of numbers for the sake of precision?
Could you please help me to solve this problem?
Thank you very much in advance.

For example,

1> MenuItem class

```
@Document(collection = "menu")
public class MenuItem {
  @Id
  private String id;

  @Field("itemName")
  @Indexed
  private String name;
  private BigDecimal cost;
```

2> create an instance of MenuItem

```
MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.setDescription("Peanutty Noodles, perfect for every occasion.");
item.setName("Yummy Noodles");
item.setCost(new BigDecimal("52.99"));


MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
item.setDescription("Rice, Egg Fried");
item.setName("Yummy Rice");
item.setCost(new BigDecimal("211.99"));
```

3> sort result

> db.menu.find().sort({cost:1})

{ "_id" : ObjectId("53e982f0300475a4fbab8c32"), "_class" : "com.yummynoodlebar.persistence.domain.MenuItem", "itemName" : "Yummy Rice", "description" : "Rice, Egg Fried", "ingredients" : [ { "name" : "Egg", "description" : "Chicken Eggs" }, { "name" : "Rice", "description" : "Straight White Rice" } ], "cost" : "211.99", "minutesToPrepare" : 0 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("53e982f0300475a4fbab8c33"), "_class" : "com.yummynoodlebar.persistence.domain.MenuItem", "itemName" : "Yummy Rice", "description" : "Rice, Egg Fried", "ingredients" : [ { "name" : "Egg", "description" : "Chicken Eggs" }, { "name" : "Rice", "description" : "Straight White Rice" } ], "cost" : "211.99", "minutesToPrepare" : 0 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("53e982f0300475a4fbab8c2f"), "_class" : "com.yummynoodlebar.persistence.domain.MenuItem", "itemName" : "Yummy Noodles", "description" : "Peanutty Noodles, perfect for every occasion.", "ingredients" : [ { "name" : "Peanuts", "description" : "A Nut" }, { "name" : "Egg", "description" : "Used in the noodles" }, { "name" : "Noodles", "description" : "Crisp, lovely noodles" } ], "cost" : "52.99", "minutesToPrepare" : 0 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("53e982f0300475a4fbab8c30"), "_class" : "com.yummynoodlebar.persistence.domain.MenuItem", "itemName" : "Yummy Noodles", "description" : "Peanutty Noodles, perfect for every occasion.", "ingredients" : [ { "name" : "Peanuts", "description" : "A Nut" }, { "name" : "Egg", "description" : "Used in the noodles" }, { "name" : "Noodles", "description" : "Crisp, lovely noodles" } ], "cost" : "52.99", "minutesToPrepare" : 0 }

{ "_id" : ObjectId("53e982f0300475a4fbab8c31"), "_class" : "com.yummynoodlebar.persistence.domain.MenuItem", "itemName" : "Yummy Noodles", "description" : "Peanutty Noodles, perfect for every occasion.", "ingredients" : [ { "name" : "Egg", "description" : "Used in the noodles" }, { "name" : "Peanuts", "description" : "A Nut" }, { "name" : "Noodles", "description" : "Crisp, lovely noodles" } ], "cost" : "52.99", "minutesToPrepare" : 0 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `BigDecimal` is [not supported](http://osdir.com/ml/mongodb-user/2011-05/msg01418.html) by MongoDB natively. That's why we convert it into `String`s by default.

For a more numeric handling, especially if you deal with prices or the like, we usually recommend to rather store doubles instead and convert them into `BigDecimal`s for arithmetic operations in the domain object directly.

Comment: Standard rules of floating point precision and roundtripping apply.   You can do it, but caveats apply.

Answer (score 2):

Since version **3.4**, MongoDB has added the support for "BigDecimal" by the new decimal data type (decimal128). However, spring data still maps the Java `BigDecimal` to MongoDB `string` by default (I guess this is for backward compatibility). The good news is the default mapping can simply be overridden by injecting a `CustomConversions` in the spring boot application as follows:

```
@Bean
CustomConversions customConverions() {
  Converter<Decimal128, BigDecimal> decimal128ToBigDecimal = new Converter<Decimal128, BigDecimal>() {
    @Override
    public BigDecimal convert(Decimal128 s) {
      return s==null ? null : s.bigDecimalValue();
    }
  };

  Converter<BigDecimal, Decimal128> bigDecimalToDecimal128 = new Converter<BigDecimal, Decimal128>() {
    @Override
    public Decimal128 convert(BigDecimal s) {
      return s==null ? null : new Decimal128(s);
    }
  };

  return new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(decimal128ToBigDecimal, bigDecimalToDecimal128));
}
```

Please check [this post for more detailed information and even a complete example](http://www.mytechtip.com/2018/01/sort-bigdecimal-mongodb-spring-data.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with Money -- and "cost" looks like that -- then use a Money class in your code.  Money will carry amount and currency.   Money has methods to fetch the amount as a BigDecimal, etc.   Persist money in MongoDB as rich shape like this:

{ cost: { amt: 21199, ccode: "USD" }}

All same-currency numeric ops (eq, gt, lt, etc.) work precisely.
And you cannnot do cross-currency comparison in the database anyway because the exchange rate is dynamic.

http://www.moschetti.org/rants/mongomoney.html

Comment: I had to go with a similar solution: use a specialized class and store the values as cents.